# Is it possible to compile both VS and PS in a single file in VS2012?

Tags: hlsl, visual-studio

`VS2012` has a built-in option for compiling `*.hlsl` files at compile time (e.g. to check for errors). But from what I've seen it requires me to provide the entry point (function) name for each file. What if I have both `Vertex Shader` and `Pixel Shader` in 1 file? Is it possible to make `VS2012` still compile that file (both shaders) to check for errors?

I know it's possible with `Custom Build Tool` option and using `fxc` in the `Command Line` (I just tell it to compile the file without specifying the entry point). But since by default `VS2012` is using `fxc` as well I thought it should be possible to compile 2 shaders in a single file when choosing `HLSL Compiler` option, too.

Comment: Ok, so choosing `Effect (/fx)` as `Shader Type` seems to do the trick. Albeit I'm not 100% sure if that's the correct solution since **I'm not using dx effects, I'm using "clean" HLSL shaders**. Can anyone confirm/deny?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not meant to work that way.  The HLSL compiler options in VS2012 aren't there to just check your files for errors; they're designed to actually *compile* the shaders to HLSL bytecode, which you can then load and pass directly to `CreatePixelShader` etc. in your program.

While you can put both vertex and pixel shader code in the same file, the trouble is it takes two `fxc` calls to generate the bytecode for both, and the bytecodes need to be output to separate files.  Visual Studio doesn't have any easy way to configure this situation, since normally a single source file generates a single output file, not two.  (In a makefile, on the other hand, it would be trivial to do this.)

Compiling as an "effect" is something totally different.  It allows multiple shaders in the same file, but you must use the technique/pass syntax to specify the entry points, and then you must use the Effects11 library at runtime to work with the shader.  You cannot pass effect bytecode directly to `CreatePixelShader` and friends.

Comment: Since my goal is to get the debugging tool and not the compiled objects, is there any way to achieve that in VS2012?

Comment: @NPS If the HLSL compiler actually error-checks everything in the file, you could just set it up to compile the pixel shader and assume the vertex shader will be error-checked as well.  You'd have to test if that works.

Comment: Seems to be checking **the whole** file but I cannot say if it checks **everything**. But thx for the tip.

Comment: Update - just found out that unfortunately it doesn't check the whole file. So is there any other solution?

Comment: @NPS Not with the standard Visual Studio build system.  As mentioned, it only understands one output file per source file.